# Column overflow with \category in ACM proceedings template

Tags: line-breaking, acm

I'm stuck using the `acm_proc_article-sp` class. The `\category` section is significantly overrunning the column width and infringing on the right column. I have been able to fix this by adding a `\sloppy`, but this of course makes the rest of the article look bad. Is there an alternative approach which will fix just the overflow? Below is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
% \sloppy %% This is necessary to fix the overflow of categories and
\conferenceinfo{X}{XXX}

\title{My title}
\numberofauthors{1} 

\author{
\alignauthor
Me\\
       \affaddr{My Institution}\\
       \affaddr{Street Address} \\
       \affaddr{City, Postcode, Country}\\
       \email{blah@blah.blah}
}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
Abstract.
\end{abstract}


% A category with the (minimum) three required fields
\category{K.4.0}{Computers and Society}[General]
\category{K.4.1}{Computers and Society}{Public Policy Issues}[Ethics]
\category{K.6.0}{Management of Computing and Information Systems}{General}[Economics]
\category{K.7.4}{The Computing Profession}{Professional Ethics}[Codes of Ethics]

\terms{Human Factors}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit the scope of `\sloppy` by wrapping the section containing `\category`-ies inside a group:

```
{\sloppy
% A category with the (minimum) three required fields
\category{K.4.0}{Computers and Society}[General]
\category{K.4.1}{Computers and Society}{Public Policy Issues}[Ethics]
\category{K.6.0}{Management of Computing and Information Systems}{General}[Economics]
\category{K.7.4}{The Computing Profession}{Professional Ethics}[Codes of Ethics]
\par
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Markdown corrections and use of the lipsum package have been noted.

Comment: @Werner For my edification, why is the \par required. I noted that without that the problem is not fixed.

Comment: a similar limiting approach: wrap the offending section between `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}`.  (i find it easier to spot the end environment in the source file than a lonely close brace, regardless of how good brace-matching is in my editor.)

Comment: @R.Schumacher -- paragraph-wide settings, including baselines and spacing adjustments, aren't applied until a paragraph actually ends, and just a closing brace doesn't end it.  (another reason to prefer the `sloppypar` environment.)

Comment: @R.Schumacher: The `\category`-ies are set in regular horizontal mode... just like anything else in a paragraph. If you close the scope of `\sloppy` *before* there is any signal of a paragraph (like an explicit `\par` or an empty/blank line), then `\sloppy` doesn't take effect. It's similar to writing limited-scope font switches `{\Large blah blah}` and then not issuing the `\par` *inside* the group `{..}`.